# Using a onKeyDown event with CharCode

Tags: javascript, keyboard, onkeydown, audio-player

I'm making my own player with drumpad and i need help to assign functions to keyboard keys. I've got playlist with (now) 3 sounds:

```
var playlist = [
    {
        artist: "Snare",
        title: "Snare",
        source: "Snare.wav"
    },
    {
        artist: "Kick",
        title: "Kick",
        source: "Kick.wav"
    },
    {
        artist: "Clap",
        title: "Clap",
        source: "Clap.wav"
    },
];
```

I've got some functions which i'm running by buttons:

```
var currentSong = 0;

var play = function() {
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio1");
    audio.play();
}
var pause = function() {
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio1");
    audio.pause();
}
var jeden = function() {
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio1");
    currentSong = 0;
    audio.src = playlist[currentSong].source;
}
var dwa = function() {
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio1");
    currentSong = 1;
    audio.src = playlist[currentSong].source;
}
var trzy = function() {
    var audio = document.getElementById("audio1");
    currentSong = 2;
    audio.src = playlist[currentSong].source;
}
```

And the html:

```
<body>
    <audio autoplay="autoplay" ontimeupdate="showinfo()" id="audio1" 
           controls="controls"></audio>
    <br/>
    <button onclick="jeden()">1</button>
    <button onclick="dwa()">2</button>
    <button onclick="trzy()">3</button>
</body>
```

I think the essiest way is to assign buttons to keyboard keys. Anybody can help me?

Comment: have you get the right solution?

Answer (score 0):

dzień dobry

The code will be something like this.    You can change keypress() to keyup() or keydown() if suitable - check the documentation of those functions to appreciate the differences.

```
$('body').keypress(function( event ) {
  if ( event.which == 49 ) {
     jeden();
  }
});
```

I referred to this page to determine the number 49 means key 1:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/

I should mention this is a jQuery solution and you will need to learn some basic jQuery setup.  It is a popular approach to solving this problem.   You will also be able to use jQuery to do your existing stuff a much nicer way.

Here is an example.   https://jsfiddle.net/7j0krzx5/

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$(document ).on( "keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.which === 80) // P key
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        // do something e.g
    }
    else if (event.which === 78) // N key
    {
        event.preventDefault();    
        // do something
    }
    // console.log(event.which);
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3b4u3jxn/)

If you don't want to use jquery

```
var play = function() {
    alert("Play");
}
var next = function() {
    alert("Next");
}
function keyDownListener(event){
   var keyCode = ('which' in event) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if(keyCode === 80){ // P key
        event.preventDefault();
        play()
    }
    else if (keyCode == 78 ) { // N key
        event.preventDefault();
        next();
    }
}
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownListener, false);
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7vspz4u4/)